# How to limit the image width of ngx-image-cropper to its popup container

Tags: angular

I have a popup with dimension (WIDTH,HEIGHT) and ngx-image-cropper (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper)  inside

```
<div mat-dialog-container>

    <image-cropper
        [imageBase64]="imageFile"
        [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
        [aspectRatio]="aspectRatio"    
        [cropperStaticWidth]="cropperStaticWidth"
        [cropperStaticHeight]="cropperStaticHeight"
        [hideResizeSquares]="true"
        format="png"
        (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
        (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
        (cropperReady)="cropperReady()"
        (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
    ></image-cropper> 
</div>
```

in my example, the imageFile size is 819 * 202 and when I inspect the img tag of   (dimension: width= 749,933; height=184,967)
it exceeds the dimension of the popup (in my case, width = 698)

I want the  tag width of   fit the width of the popup with a margin of 10px on left side as well as right side

Comment: Please add a starting point in code (like StackBlitz) to show the problem and get your question quickly solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am dizzy, I put by mistake a div as container of tag image-cropper with width = 460 and height = 425. I removed it and now it is working.

Sorry again

Comment: can u add stackblitz this. I'm facing static dimensions issue similar like this